# saving illustrator file in photoshop after edit as?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, images, save, raster

new to using illustrator.. (and in combination with photoshop)
have photographic images i've added a single line of text to 
in AI.. reimported image to PS to retouch.. now can i save 
the file again as jpg? to be used as a banner image on website.
will be large 1680 by 1100. will type be OK?

Comment: Hi julia, welcome to GDSE. I'm afraid your question isn't at all clear. Please [edit] your question to clarify what you're trying to do and where exactly you're struggling. If you're asking whether a certain file type will be OK, then please specify what your intended use is. Thanks for your time and effort.

Answer (score 1):

Saving the image as is should be as simple as File > Save As, type in a filename and select .jpeg from the type pulldown. However I would not suggest you do this for two reasons.

First the JPEG format cannot save [vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics) information such as the curves used to define the shapes of your text, or layer information. So the text will have to be rasterized and the layers flattened which will be significantly damaging to the quality of the text and your ability to edit the document in the future. Depending on the size and style of text this might not be a huge issue, but it will be noticable.

The other issue I see is the resoultion you're suggesting. At this size your image will consume the entirety of the screen. I'm unclear if this is your intention or if you are unaware that web images have a fixed [pixel density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_density). You can fudge the size of the image down using CSS or height/width attributes, but you'd probably be better off resizing it in PhotoShop so you have control over how it is resampled.

My suggestion would be to avoid these issues by using the original image as a fixed background with text placed over top via HTML.